# Count multiple of a number in a given range with O(1) complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, factors

**We are given three numbers, L, R and K. We need to count numbers between L and R (inclusive both) which are divisible by K.**

Is it possible to solve with O(1) complexity?

It is a very simple program I know, can be easily done with a loop. But I was wondering if it is possible to apply some kind of formula or something to directly know the count of numbers which are divisible by K between L and R.

For example, `count = (R - L + 1) / K` will probably work in some of the cases.

Anything?

Comment: Please do not use links in questions on SO since they can die sometime in the future and the the question becomes useless. Please describe the question here.

Comment: Your example will work in some of the cases - all you need to do it check the end cases (whether `r % k = 0` or not, etc.)

Comment: The title is very misleading as describes a probably much harder problem.  You want to count **multiples** of a number in a given range.

Comment: @j_random_hacker This is how it was explained at HackerEarth, from where I took the problem. Check it out https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/count-divisors/

Comment: Well, they called it simply "Count Divisors", which is more unclear than wrong, and your title "Count the factors (or divisors) *of a number*", in making the statement clearer, also makes clearer why it's wrong -- they are not counting the divisors *of* any particular number.  (The divisors or factors of 10 are 1, 2, 5 and 10, for example.)  So please fix your title and I'll drop the -1.

Comment: @j_random_hacker allright, i have changed the title. hope it's clear now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your solution.

```
 quo1=l/k;
 quo2=r/k;
 rem=l%k;
 if(rem==0)
 {
   count=quo2-quo1+1;
 }
 else
 {
    count=quo2-quo1;
  }
```

Comment: You can instead do `r/k - (l - 1) / k` (assuming l, r, k are natural)

Comment: Cool, that seems more simpler.